# InAppPurchase not working in app which is downloaded from AppStore!

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

My in-app purchase status shows "ready for sale" in itunes and i downloaded my app from the appStore...
But the store returning 0 products...Not possible to purchase any items.. What might be the problem? Any Idea?
app is released on 18-Apr-2011 to canada store only....  Is it take time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way to general for SO. Your going to need to show us specific code, or contact Apple App Store support and make sure your products are correctly populating etc.

Comment: Did it work in your testing? Is it an update to an existing app, or a brand new one?

Comment: Ya it is working correctly in sandbox mode...

Comment: Do i need to remove test user or sandbox mode...

Comment: Do i need to remove test user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the reason... but the apple guys took 24 hours to enable inApp-purchase now it is working fine...
App is released on 18-Apr-2011 and inApp purchase started working from 19-Apr-2011...

Answer (score 1):

please check bundle identifier. it may be change or may be some space at the end. because if store return 0 product means there is no product for the given bundle identifier.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same scenerion in my app..the apple wasnt verify the product id during the first 24 hrs and so it was giving invalid product id error which in turn was generating the "in-app purchase failed" error..And then after 24 hrs (may b a little earlier than that) the in app purchase started working perfectly fine...

In-App in my app was released on 20th april..Kept on giving the error...
In App started working fine on 21st April...!

Comment: Apple should solve this issue... I spent unnecessarily a day to check n solve the issue...